# What is the difference between Management console and Dashboard of WSO2IS

Tags: wso2-identity-server

can anyone please explain me the difference between management console and dashboard of WSO2 Identity server?

Answer (score 1):

I hope following documentations will help you to identify the differences between management console and dashboard.

https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS530/Getting+Started+with+the+Management+Console
https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS530/Using+the+End+User+Dashboard

Comment: Thank you!
This is helpful but can you tell me backend services which are used to login to management console as well as dashboard

Answer (score 1):

In General, **Management Console** is basically another UI for managing a primary or main application. A Single management console can consists of multiple **dashboards** based on roles or other crteria for managing the application.